# Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "localhost:3306"'

Tags: java, mysql

So I have just these two lines...

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connectionToSql = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://:localhost:3306/questions", "root", "root");
```

And I get exception saying:

```
Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "localhost:3306"'.
```

What should I do?

Comment: There's a `:` after `..mysql://`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ":" before localhost